# What are the base layers of Docker's Python image

Tags: python, image, docker

I've looked everywhere but it seems a complete breakdown of the actual layers isn't available (at least I can't find it).

I'm new to Docker and I'm trying to understand everything on how the system works. I've understood **the layer system that Docker uses to create and store its images.**

Now my issue is to understand exactly which layers are present inside the official Docker Python image. From my computer knowledge, I know that Python needs some sort of "foundations" to work. This thought has been partially confirmed by the fact that, on the Docker Python image [webpage](https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=tags&page=1&name=slim) you can actually see the OS/ARC the image is based on.

For instance, if we take the [slim-buster image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/slim-buster/images/sha256-4d4dac46a3a09a0989673b6a3422925b97c2027735d1a3ae9b22887f32a9260e?context=explore), according to the webpage, **I can count several operations executed.**

My question is: **are those operations the actual layer** or, are the layers simply two? The OS/Kernel layer and the actual Python layer?

Comment: @HansKilian so, the first ADD command I see, can I say that it's the actual OS/kernel to run Python?

Comment: I changed my comment to an answer and elaborated a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layers you can see on the web page you linked are the actual layers. So there are 15 layers in that image.

Some of the layers do a lot of work, like the first one which ADDed a tar ball and extracted it. That tar ball contains a lot of files.

Most commands in a Dockerfile result in the creation of a new layer.

You can usually trace the complete Dockerfiles back to the origin since a lot of them are open source.

The python:slim-buster Dockerfile is here: https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/8d48af512dc58e9c29c9d4ee59477c195a29cbdc/3.10/buster/slim/Dockerfile

At the top, you can see that the base image is `debian:buster-slim`. With a bit of googeling, you can find the Dockerfile for that here: https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/blob/d99a48edaa18ad2bbb260c388b274c8c093f2d32/buster/slim/Dockerfile

That image is based on `scratch` which is an empty image. So that's the end of the chain. The tar file in the ADD command in the debian:buster-slim image basically contains the complete Debian setup needed to run Debian.

Something interesting to note in the Python Dockerfile is that a lot of the RUN statements contain a lot of commands chained together with `&&`. That's done to reduce the number of layers. If each single command in those RUN statements were on it's own RUN statement, there'd be a lot more layers.